# What is this Terminal (or Micro)

Tags: identify-this-peripheral

I came across this picture, part of this collection, taken by [Martin Langer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Langer_(Fotograf)) for [this collection](https://langerphoto.de/fotogalleries/land-des-laechelns/), possibly in northern Germany (Ostwestfahlen) in 1982/1983

[image]

What terminal or micro computer is shown here? Bonus points for identifying the printer as well.

The logo looks a bit like Wang, just I do not remember any Wang looking alike. Though, around 1980s they brought a lot of short lived products.

Comment: Proposed Title: "Outage". Caption: "Early example of a first-world problem."

Comment: It seems this picture is in a book called "Das Land Des Lächelns: Eine westdeutsche Provinz in der 80ern" (Martin Langer). Maybe there are more references there to pinpoint exact year and where it was taken if you can find that book?

Comment: That monitor shape, while distinctive, doesn't look like any picture of a Wang that I can find, particularly for the early 80's when they often had empty space to the right of the screen.

Comment: I asked the contact page on the website for more information on the photo - when, where, who is the subject - that may shed some light.

Comment: Being Germany, my guess would be Nixdorf. They had terminals with flat anti-glare coverings like this one.

Comment: @rbanffy It would be even their home region, but nop, They had a very distinctive shape, lower keyboards and a dark grey colouring scheme.

Comment: @Raffzahn it could be an older terminal. The printer looks relatively modern, with straight lines and what looks like an early 90's color scheme, but, also, there is a typewriter with moving carriage next to it, so it's almost like a mashup of different periods.

Comment: @rbanffy The picture is taken in 1982, so definitely not modern. Colour scheme looks like some TA devices, but none I recognize. The whole setup is a mystery.

Comment: @Raffzahn only now I noticed the printer has a reel of paper instead of the more usual fanfold - this could narrow the possibilities somehow. In 1982, however, the Nixdorf terminals, as you point out, had nicer designs and low-profile keyboards. They also lacked some of the extra angles this unit has. Finally, the blurred logo doesn't match anything Nixdorf could have used then.

Comment: @rbanffy Thanks for investing serious time :)) That picture puzzles me for quite some time. Nothing really matches,so it must be some forgotten sideline, making it even more interesting.

Comment: No worries, @Raffzahn. I am a retrocomputing geek after all and I'm sure you'd do the same for me.

Comment: The logo seems to have two words, but it's longer than "Norsk Data."